# Change Notification Content Extension Interface Size Xamarin iOS

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, notification-content-extension

I've implemented a notification content extension in order to get action buttons to show up properly in my app. All I need for my notifications is the default header and the action buttons, no interface. As such, I want to hide the interface or shrink its size to zero but nothing has worked.

Here is what is showing:
[image]

I've tried updating the size in `ViewDidLoad()` in the `ViewController` like so:

```
        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            PreferredContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0, 0);
            ContentSizeForViewInPopover = PreferredContentSize;
            

            View.SetNeedsUpdateConstraints();
            View.SetNeedsLayout();
            UpdateViewConstraints();            

            // Do any required interface initialization here.
        }
```

I've tried changing the `ViewController` to `FreeForm` in XCode and setting its Width and Height to 0
[image]

I've also set the width and height to the view in the storeboard file to 0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="M4Y-Lb-cyx">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21679"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Notification View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="cwh-vc-ff4">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="M4Y-Lb-cyx" userLabel="Notification View Controller" customClass="NotificationViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="sVI-DA-27z"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="WK5-y5-Ae8"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" simulatedAppContext="notificationCenter" id="S3S-Oj-5AN">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="0" height="0"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.45882353186607361" green="0.74901962280273438" blue="0.66666668653488159" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                    <value key="contentSizeForViewInPopover" type="size" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                    <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="vXp-U4-Rya" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="-33" y="-8"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Nothing has worked. How can I shrink / hide / remove the interface in the push notification so that it only has the header and the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Setting the Notification Content Extension's categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#setting-the-notification-content-extensions-categories), you may try the following things to remove the content:

1.[Setting the content area size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#setting-the-content-area-size)

Edit the Info.plist file for the Extension and set the **UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio** key of the **NSExtensionAttribute**s key to type Number with a very small value, such as zero.

2.[Hiding the default notification content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#hiding-the-default-notification-content)

Add the **UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden** key to the **NSExtensionAttributes** key as type Boolean with a value of YES in the Extension's Info.plist file.

For more info, you could refer to Apple's doc for [UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes/unnotificationextensioninitialcontentsizeratio?language=objc)
.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I forgot the mention but, yea, I fixed it but setting UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio  to 0 in the .plist